# 'X'-close button on iPhone

Tags: buttons, search, iphone, ios, cancel

The default way of dismissing views in iOS is with `Cancel` or `Done`. However in this view I think `Cancel` uses to much space, which is better given to the search bar.

[image: example ui]

What is your opinion? Is using `X` in this situation as a replacement for cancel acceptable or a no go?

Comment: @Mohit Yes I realized that the "close"-button and the button to clear the searchbar are having the same icon. That's what makes me unsure about using it as close button. 
So you think it's not acceptabel?

Comment: Stick to iOS standards when they exist.  In this case they do, so use what iOS users are used to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do realize that you have two almost identical "close" buttons in the screenshot above?!

Don't you think that just this issue makes the usage of "close button" absolutely unacceptable? I think it does.

Two very similar looking buttons on the same screen and particularly adjacent to each other can affect usability.

In your screenshot, the *first close button* stands for deleting the already-entered text (which is an innate iPhone functionality) in the textfield while *the second one* denotes "Cancel" button (as per you). Consequently, users may find it difficult to understand the functionality of the similar looking "Cancel" button and it may affect the overall user experience.

Comment: Why is it 'absolutely unacceptable' though? Can you expand on your reasoning for this. You might be right, but currently it just reads like you don't like it for some reason. You can't have two similar buttons the same on screen *because*...

Comment: @JonW - Done....I am currently occupied, may add more soon!

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem one time. I realized that on iOS, "X" doing action like Delete/Remove. Done or Cancel as exit action are better for two reasons:

1) a lot of iOS apps do so; iPhone user will be familiar with this solution; we are avoiding users confusion like on screen you attached

2) In my opinion, search field do not need great amount of space on mobile; I dont know any reasearch about that and destination of your app, but I think that users usually type first-ten signs from keyboard (in assumption that typing from mobile is usally less comfortable than other)

Keep it simple and consistent with platform, dude. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about the Apple UI guidelines, but wouldn't this be an element that could be "hidden" instead of "closed".

I'm thinking more of an arrow icon pointing upwards: [^] It would save a lot space and is not as negative as "close" or "cancel"

Comment: Would probably make sense if the `close` would only affect the searchbar, but the `close` dismissed the complete view not just the bar.
However, Apple by default uses a `Cancel`-Button even to dismiss only the bar.